# Join argv list with spaces

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm a Python noob. This is the code I'm using:

```
for i in argv[2:]:                                 # argv[1] isn't required by s.py
    if ' ' in i:
        argv[argv.index(i)] = '"%s"' % i
args = ' '.join(argv[2:])
os.system('s.py '+args)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't use `os.system` to run commands. You should use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead, for example:

```
from sys import argv
import subprocess

cmd = 's.py'
args = [cmd] + argv[2:]
subprocess.call(args)
```

This is a lot cleaner. In your version you added quotes around the command line arguments that contained spaces. (Which btw would break spectacularly if the command line arg also contained quote character...) Using `subprocess`, you don't need such dirty hacks.

Comment: I also have to pass `python` along with `s.py` or it says `[Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: Instead of passing along `python`, better go with `sys.executable`. It is always a good idea to have as few constant values as possible in your script, and `sys.executable` always points to the python executable.

Answer (score 6):

Janos makes a good point about the code overall, but there are a few specific points on Python looping you should be aware of.

Firstly, you can `map` a function to all elements in a list:

```
args = " ".join(map(lambda s: '"%s"' % s if ' ' in s else s, args[2:]))
```

Secondly, naming an element, rather than its index, `i` is likely to confuse readers of your code.

Finally, `list.index` gives you the *first* index, which may not play well with duplicates. If you need both an element and its index you should use `enumerate`:

```
for i, s in enumerate(args[2:], 2):
```

Comment: Idiomatic Python generally prefers list comprehension over `map`: `['"%s"' % s if ' ' in s else s for s in args[2:]])`